Ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive
I am working on Eletron.js app. I am trying to access a link of figma trough a iframe, but when I try to do it, I receive the following error:

What can being cause this? It's only with the URL I am trying to use. I already have tried with others and works well. The URL I use is this, to login on figma and get a token to use an api.


Figma have configured the Content Security Policy of their webserver to only allow their site to place their content in an iframe. This is what the self means in the error message.
In short you will not be able to do this, without first coming to some form of agreement with Figma.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors
